# How to create responsive grid with two sides?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image]

I want something like this, but there is some problems.

My code looks like:

```
<style>
   .red{

   background-color: red;
   }
</style>

{% endblock stylesheets %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container-flex m-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-around mb-3">
                <div class="col-3">

                    <div class="h-150 speak p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
                        <div>
                            <h4 class=" title">TEXT</h4>
                            <h5 class=" card-text">TEXT</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="h-150 speak p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
                        <div>
                            <h4 class=" title">LONG TEXT</h4>
                            <h5 class=" card-text">TEXT</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="h-150 speak p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
                        <div>
                            <h4 class=" title">TEXT</h4>
                            <h5 class=" card-text">TEXT</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" d-flex justify-content-around mb-3">

                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="h-150 communicate p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                            <h4 class=" card-text text-capitalize">TEXT</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="h-150 internet p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                            <h4 class=" card-text">TEXT</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="h-150 internet p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                            <h4 class=" card-text">TEXT</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" d-flex justify-content-around  mb-3">

                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="h-150 communicate p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                            <h4 class=" card-text text-capitalize">TEXT</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="h-150 internet p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                            <h4 class=" card-text">LONG LONG TEXT</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="h-150 internet p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
                            <h4 class=" card-text">TEXT</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="h-150 speak p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
                <div>
                    <h4 class=" title">TEXT</h4>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But result is in photo, without correction.

Each `card` is with title, context and icon. And context som times is longer then other which also breaks up my code.

How can I set height by each element responsive? And how to create this grid on all page height with bootstrap? What I need to modify in my code to get result what is in picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `h-` class uses set percentages. If you want them to fill 100% of the available height, you just set it to `h-100`. The other side is the same way, so you can use whatever you want for that or you can do a custom percentage using CSS. `h-150` isn't a valid use of these classes (remove it and you'll notice nothing changes, it just auto fits).
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-flex m-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-around mb-3">
        <div class="col-3">

          <div class="h-100 speak p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
            <div>
              <h4 class=" title">TEXT</h4>
              <h5 class=" card-text">TEXT</h5>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="h-100 speak p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
            <div>
              <h4 class=" title">LONG TEXT</h4>
              <h5 class=" card-text">TEXT</h5>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="h-100 speak p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
            <div>
              <h4 class=" title">TEXT</h4>
              <h5 class=" card-text">TEXT</h5>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" d-flex justify-content-around mb-3">

        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="h-100 communicate p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
            <div>
              <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
              <h4 class=" card-text text-capitalize">TEXT</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="h-100 internet p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
            <div>
              <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
              <h4 class=" card-text">TEXT</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="h-100 internet p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
            <div>
              <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
              <h4 class=" card-text">TEXT</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" d-flex justify-content-around  mb-3">

        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="h-100 communicate p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
            <div>
              <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
              <h4 class=" card-text text-capitalize">TEXT</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="h-100 internet p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
            <div>
              <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
              <h4 class=" card-text">LONG LONG TEXT</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="h-100 internet p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
            <div>
              <h5 class=" title text-uppercase">TEXT</h5>
              <h4 class=" card-text">TEXT</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="min-vh-100 speak p-3 box red" style="border-radius: 5%;">
        <div>
          <h4 class=" title">TEXT</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h5 class=" card-text">ICON</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And how to set so this grid would cover all page from up to down? And also how to set right card to fill also to bottom?

Comment: @Dmiich You can use viewport units in Bootstrap as well https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-viewport I used that on your right card just as a demo. I'm not sure I'd recommend it for what you're doing with the cards but you can replace the `h-` classes with viewport units if that's what you're looking for. Make the snippet full page to see the right box extend all the way down